# "....in 10 days" or ".....after 10 days."

Tags: sentence-structure, conjunctions, sentence-usage, future-constructions, conjunction-reduction

The text is from [BBC web site](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-59343650):

*"....Under the measures, Austrians will be asked to work from home, non-essential shops will close, and schools will remain open for children who require face-to-face learning. They will continue until 12 December, but will be reassessed **after 10 days**."*

The expression **"...after 10 days"** seems a little bit unusual to me, because it refers to future. As a rule, when we talk about future, we use **"in"**, not **"after"**, or at least this is what they teach us at schools.

For instance, we say **"I will fly to London in 2 days' time."** We would not say "**I will fly to London after 10 days"**

So, my question is: Is the usage above **"...after 10 days"** a correct usage? In other words, is it correct English to use **"after"** for future like it was used by the BBC.

Comment: When quoting a website, remember to include the link to the website. It's important.

Comment: It means after 10 days have passed. It is completely standard. In ten days can mean on day 10. After 10 days means anytime after ten days have passed.

Comment: To add to what Lambie says, this wording suggests there's a requirement that they wait 10 days before reassessment, rather than a schedule to reassess 10 days later.

Answer (score 9):

OP is mistaken in thinking that native Anglophones wouldn't say *I will fly to London after 10 days*.

The only relevant factor here is that ***after** [some amount of time]* requires a ***context*** within which some particular point in time (past *or* future) has already been established. Thus...

> *I'll go to Glasgow on December the 12th, and stay with my aunt. I will fly to London after 10 days.*

...is fine. The fact that this is a reference to *future* actions is irrelevant, since we can also say...

> *I went to Glasgow in June and stayed with my aunt. I **flew** to London after 10 days.*

---

EDIT: Note that *as it happens*, I placed adverbial ***after*** BEFORE the relevant "duration, amount of time" (***10 days***, here), but syntactically speaking it would be fine (and mean exactly the same) if I'd placed it AFTER the duration *(...fly / flew to London 10 days **after***. As with many adverbs in English, the exact position is flexible - particularly if there's no scope for alternative interpretations, as is the case here.

Also note that we can replace ***after*** by ***later*** without changing the meaning - but only as ***...10 days later*** (the sequence ***later 10 days*** is never valid in English).

---

EDIT2: IMHO, the cited usage in the BBC article is poorly phrased, and even many native Anglophones might struggle to answer *"**10 days after what**?"* (in the context of *"**When will the policy of keeping schools open be reassessed**?"*).

Logically, the *only* interpretation that makes sense is *The policy of keeping schools open will be reassessed 10 days after the lockdown is introduced on Monday 22nd Nov* (i.e. - the reassessment is scheduled to take place on 2nd Dec). But the way it's phrased strongly steers us to assume the reassessment will take place ten days after the most recently-mentioned date (12th Dec), even though *logically*, that makes no sense.

*Syntactically*, it's even possible that what's to be reassessed after 10 days is the *entire* lockdown policy - but that's just another reason why I say the text isn't well constructed. I'm as certain as I can be that the *intention* is to say that specifically the policy in relation to *schools* should be reassessed after 10 days.

Comment: Would you mind terribly using the OP? OP sounds so awful to my ear. Dog will eat food after ten minutes. haha

Comment: FumbleFingers, Thanks for the answer. I understand your explanation which really is good. But this time, I got confused with the syntax. If the particular point in time (future) has already been established: Should we say "I will fly to London after 10 days." or, should we say "I will fly to London 10 days after." I mean if a particular point in time (future) has already been established, then it should be "....10 days after (that), that being the particular point in time in the future. Is that right?

Comment: @Lambie - dog of my own once—pointer—surprising instinct—out shooting one day—entering inclosure—whistled—dog stopped—whistled again—Ponto—no go; stock still—called him—Ponto, Ponto—wouldn’t move—dog transfixed—staring at a board—looked up, saw an inscription—“Gamekeeper has orders to shoot all dogs found in this inclosure”—wouldn’t pass it—wonderful dog—valuable dog that—very.’

Comment: I am a native British English speaker and I would never say (in the contexts you use) "I will fly to London after 10 days". It sounds very odd. I am not sure what your first example sentence even means - the 22nd or at some point in the future no less than 10 days later.

Comment: @yunus: Adverbs (including ***after***, here) are often very flexible about their position within a sentence. Idiomatically, *...fly/flew to London **after** 10 days* is more common that the versions I've used above, but both are syntactically fine ***and mean exactly the same***. I'm not sure exactly how to explain why, but note that the contextually-equivalent ***later*** can only be placed at the *end* of the utterance. That's to say, *I left 10 days later* is fine (and means the same as *...10 days after / ...after 10 days*), but *I left later 10 days* isn't valid.

Comment: @FrancisDavey: I'm surprised. What do you think of, for example, [My grand-daughter's face was completely healed and we were both discharged from the hospital about two weeks after and went home together.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22about+two+weeks+after+and%22&tbm=bks&ei=ZUSaYbyXHZLygQbQxonwAg&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwj83ZXxwqn0AhUSecAKHVBjAi4Q8NMDegQIARBP&biw=1354&bih=623&dpr=1.39) In that example, the established "narrative reference time" is that point in the past when the grand-daughter's face was completely healed (they left hospital 2 weeks later than that). Is that OK for you?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - it reads less oddly. "Two weeks later" or "two weeks afterwards" would work for me, but "two weeks after" reads like it is missing something. However, I do understand its meaning. The "about" helps explain the vagueness.

Comment: @FrancisDavey: I can't see that "vagueness" about the exact duration makes any difference. Syntactically speaking, that hospital example could just as well have said *...we were both discharged from the hospital exactly 14 days after...*  - the only reason it would be "weird" to be that specific is that the *starting point* for that duration is "when her face healed" (not exactly an "event" that could be specified to the nearest minute / second! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "I will fly to London after 10 days" - I can't tell whether that means exactly 10 days, but that is not the main difficulty. The main difficulty is that I'm not conscious of hearing and would never use the construction. I find myself asking "after what". For me there needs to be something like "afterwards". Indeed, that's why I have the word "afterwards".

Comment: @FrancisDavey: If I'd put ***after*** AFTER the duration, I could advise you to "parse" it as *I will fly to London 10 days after **that***, where ***that*** refers to the previously-mentioned projected future activity "flying to Glasgow". Which is explicitly assigned an actual date (12th Dec), but "post-positive" *[10 days] **after*** can in principle refer to some preceding activity that hasn't actually been *given* an exact date/time anyway.

Comment: ...it's a bit harder to "explain" the syntax if ***after*** comes BEFORE the duration. *I will fly to London **after** 10 days*. I suppose I'd have to say that implies *after 10 days **of being in Glasgow***, but I'm not sure how helpful that perspective is.

Comment: I am a native speaker of American English and like Francis Davey, I would also never say that. And if I heard someone say it I would immediately assume English was not their native language.

Comment: @ReggieSimmons: Well, Francis said "I am a native British English speaker", so this is obviously nothing to do with a UK/US usage split. It's not difficult to find plenty of written instances of adverbial constructions liker ***after 10 days*** AND ***10 days after***, so all I can do is repeat what I said before: I'm surprised. But there *are* many syntactic / idiomatic peculiarities in this area - for example, AFTER the duration (but not BEFORE), ***after*** can be directly replaced by ***afterwards*** (latterly, it's usually ***afterward*** in the US, as with ***toward, forward***, etc.).

Comment: It is ambiguous but my understanding of the news excerpt is the following: The Austrian government measures will last until 12 December: a total of twenty days. The situation will be analysed **after  ten days have passed** (22 December). If during that period the rate of infection has not increased (or whatever agreed upon criteria) the emergency lockdown will not be reintroduced. The "they" refers to the Austrian measures not to the evaluation of school children.

Comment: This also means between December 12 and December 22 there will be sufficient time for consumers to "consume" **in time** for Christmas.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: It should be easy enough to establish the real-world truth as to the timeframe of the Austrian measures and review dates, but I wouldn't treat that as conclusive evidence as to ***what the actual text here "means"***. I'm 100% committed to the interpretation that ***after 10 days*** means ***10 days after the measures are introduced***, not 10 days after the measures are ***lifted***. But that's because to me it's the only interpretation that makes sense. The actual text is ambiguous as regards the referent of ***after 10 days*** (with ***...10 days later*** slightly less so).

Comment: Your answer mentions: "*The policy of **keeping schools open** will be reassessed **10 days after the lockdown is introduced** on Monday 22nd Nov*" that this situation affects **only the schools**  is not explicitly mentioned in the text, so we have to take it to infer the temporary lockdown might be **reintroduced after** Dec 22.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Like I say, there are better ways to find out what the actual *policy* is in the real world. All I'm saying is the text as presented here is imho badly-worded and ambiguous (where "imho" is just a courtesy, since I'm sure I have the credentials to label a text "badly-worded", and *by definition*, if I see ambiguity there *is* ambiguity). *And* I happen to think that "reassessing a lockdown" 10 days after lifting it doesn't make sense, but that really is just an opinion.

Comment: (Note that I never intended to imply that only the "schools-related" part of the lockdown would be reassessed. I just thought it would be *more* "distracting" if I'd copied the entire referent with appropriate restructuring for syntactic reasons: *The policy of **making people work from home, closing non-essential shops, and keeping schools open** will be reassessed 10 days after the lockdown is introduced on Monday 22nd Nov* :)

Comment: (...or ***...keeping non-essential shops closed...*** At some point the law of diminishing returns kicks in.)

Comment: I suggest that you read the closing line of your answer: `I'm as certain as I can be that the intention is to say that specifically the policy in relation to schools should be reassessed`

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I think the law of diminishing returns has already kicked in. The text is inherently ambiguous, and apparently I'm more inclined to a different interpretation than you (I believe, *because we have different ideas about what "makes sense" in the real world*). My reasoning is simply that I assume it's much easier for a government to open or close schools at short notice (after all, nearly all the people who work in them are paid by the State). They can't so casually alter the rules regarding private companies forcing employees to work from home, or forcing shops to close.

Answer (score 4):

Breaking it down:

- The vaccination was **in April.**
- You could get the booster **after six months** [had passed].

In other words, **as of September onwards**.

Likewise:
They will continue until 12 December, but will be reassessed **after 10 days**."

That means **as of 22 December**, those measures will be reassessed. **Anytime AFTER that**. It is not specific.

Those measures will be reassessed **in 10 days**= exact. Day 1 + 10. **Only on December 22.**

Those measures will be reassessed **within 10 days**.
**Before the 10 days are finished**.

This is just a general guide. **Sometimes "in" is used for the "within" idea.** But not in carefully written pieces.

Comment: @Mari-LouA They (**the measures**). yes. They will be reassessed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think the distinction here is when you start counting.

"I will fly to London in ten days' time" means ten days from now, the time of speaking. If you want to start counting the ten days from some other point, you would use "after" (or "later"), for example "I will go to New York, then fly to London after ten days" means that the ten days start when you arrive in New York ("... fly to London ten days later" would have the same meaning).

In context, the article starts

> Days after Austria imposed a lockdown on the unvaccinated, it has announced a full national Covid-19 lockdown starting on Monday [22nd].

The article itself was written on Saturday 20th. So "after ten days" means that it will be reassessed on 2nd December (ten days after the lockdown starts), whereas "in ten days" would have meant on 30th November (ten days from the time of writing). The latter would also be poor reporting - you don't know exactly when the article will be read, so the best way to express "ten days from the time of writing" would be "on 30th November".

Answer (score 2):

There's a fairly subtle difference in meaning here.  After 10 days means that the measures are in place now, and their effects will be reassessed after having 10 days experience with them.

If you say you will do something in 10 days, that implies that you are not doing it now, and won't be doing it until those 10 days have passed.

Comment: Re your second paragraph, it's also quite possible to say something like *I can't start your job until next month, but once I can get started, **I'll do it in 10 days***. Normally meaning the *duration* of the job will be 10 days, but in some circumstances that might mean *10 days of **work*** (spread over two weeks or more, but the work will be booked / charged as 10 days, regardless of elapsed time).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: But after 10 days of working on it, I tell the customer that I'll have it done in 20 days :-)

Comment: I can see you'll be successful as a self-employed contractor! If they query the bill for 20 days of your time presented 10 days after you started the job, just tell them you had to hire a guy to work alongside you!

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an article about Austria, and I am Austrian, I guess there is something I can add as detail. I found quite the same statement in German (Austria's native language) at [www.austria.info](https://www.austria.info/de/service-und-fakten/coronavirus-situation-in-oesterreich) on 21st of November, so one day before the lockdown begins:

> Dieser Lockdown ab Montag, 22. November wird **nach** 10 Tagen evaluiert und soll spätestens mit 13. Dezember enden.

Emphasis by me. I emphasised the word *nach*, which literally means *after*.
Translation by me:

> This lockdown starting with Monday, 22nd of November will be reassessed **after** 10 days and should end latest with 13th of December.

If the German sentence contained the word *in* (engl. *in*) instead of *nach* (engl. *after*), I would translate it with *in* but understand it differently:

- When I read this sentence on Friday, 19th of November (the lockdown was issued on Thursday for entire Austria), I assume that *in 10 Tagen* (*in 10 days*) means: 19th of November (from when I read it or from when the article was published) plus 10 days, which is 29th of November.
- However, *nach 10 Tagen* (*after 10 days*) means: Measured from the 22nd, which is Thursday, the 2nd of December. That sounds more plausible, since the Austrian Corona commission meets every Thursday.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, this kind of use falls into a commonly used phrasing:

"[Action will be performed on Subject] after [Condition is fulfilled]"

For example:
"I will eat this apple **after** I have brushed my teeth"
"The money will enter my account **after** proof of identification has been provided"

The example in the OP is the same:

"[The situation] will be reassessed **after** 10 days"

However, as pointed out in the comments, it's important to note that this would actually be understood as

"[The situation] will be reassessed after 10 days **have passed** "

Note that while some people use "once" interchangeably with "after" in the context of this phrasing structure, "it will be reassessed once 10 days" doesn't make any sense at all.